# Mulit OS Live DVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, livedvd

similar question asked earlier about multi USB (thanks, excellent answer); is it possible to have multiple **Live OS**'s on a single **DVD**?  4 specifically, one being windows, the others linux based; with a "chooser" - i'm fairly sure you can't because you can't partition a DVD (or can you!?!) Some of the computers here will not boot from a USB (that's how old they are); so i have to keep 4 dvd's on hand at all times.

Comment: You can burn a PLOP boot CD  and that will boot the USB stick in old PCs. And no, Windows installer needs its own media and a DVD is too small for what you want anyway.

Comment: And the Multisystem I mentioned in your other question can also create a bootable CD to use along the Multisystem USB.

Comment: thanks @MichaelBay will be combining all the information you provided, and am looking forward to the next transformers movie

Comment: @MichaelBay if you wanted the credit, feel free to post that as an answer for me to accept, as it is what i did